# Is there a translation of "twentysomething"?

Tags: numbers

Sometimes it is desirable to express a number dropping the information about the last digit.

> - Ich bin neunundzwanzig → Ich bin ???zwanzig.

Or

> - Ja, ich habe nicht zu viel Geld ausgegeben. Nur neunundzwanzigtausend Euro

is, of course, more convincing if we could drop the *neun*:

> - Ja, ich habe nicht zu viel Geld ausgegeben. Nur ???zwanzigtausend Euro

The swapping of pairs of digits in the number representation in German, with respect to the "natural" decreasing order of the powers, i.e.

[image]

makes the question tricky. For one could try, for instance, with

> Etwas-zwanzig

but how to let somebody know that this *etwas* stands for a positive number less than 10 and not for hundreds? I mean, that could also mean 220 instead of *twentysomething*.

---

*Edit:* I forgot to mention that it would be nice if the answer contains a *twentysomething* that applies for every situation (if such a thing exists).

Comment: Ich würde zwanzigirgendwas verwenden. Statt zwanzig-irgendwas-tausend würde ich eher `etwas mehr als zwanzigtausend`

Comment: Die "-irdendwas" Übersetzung von "-something" durch @knut ist meines Erachtens die beste Übersetzung. Alle anderen sind entweder regionale Redewendungen oder entsprechen nur teilweise dem englischen Ausdruck.

Comment: Ich habe aus meinem Kommentar mal eine Antwort gemacht.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This depends on the context. Regarding age, you could say

> Ich bin in den Zwanzigern.

meaning 20 <= age < 30

or

> Ich bin Anfang / Ende Zwanzig.

(with "Anfang" meaning between 20 and 25 and "Ende" between 25 and 30.)

With money, see knut's comment; in colloquial language, often "20 Euro und ein paar Zerquetschte" is used (but i wouldn't expect this for, e.g., 29 Euro). Regarding 29 (or 29.000), usually something like "fast 30 / 30.000" oder "beinahe 30 / 30.000" is used.

If you want to indicate an amount of money very roughly, you could also use

> Ein niedriger dreistelliger Betrag

(meaning an amount between 100 and ~ 300)

or

> Ein höherer fünfstelliger Betrag

(meaning an amount between ~ 75.000 and 99.999).

Comment: Neben 20-irgendwas hört man auch 20-nochwas. "25-plus-minus" trifft nicht ganz Bedeutung von über 19 und unter 30.

Answer (score 8):

**This answer is about the usage in speech:**
*all given possibilities are regional for the area around Stuttgart*

In this context one uses *"paar"*

> paar-und-zwanzig

is what you are looking for.
this can also be used with your example, given the case, your *c* is defined.

also often used is:

> *C*hundert ungerade

though more in the context of higher powers...

Comment: IMHO "paarundzwanzig" is quite rarely used - but it seems to be quite useful. Google NGram Viewer doesn't even know it.

Comment: @tohuwawohu it is only used in speech...

Comment: @tohuwawohu Maybe it depends on region, but I often use it and hear it as well.

Comment: paar-und-zwanzig? In welcher Gegend wird denn das verwendet? Habe ich noch nie gehört.

Comment: @schlingel ich komme von den Fildern, habe Verwandte in Hessen. In beiden Gebieten (Stuttgart und Gießen) habe ich das schon gehört

Comment: @Vogel612 Ah, danke für die Info. Interessant, nur ein bisschen weiter südlich und das wirkt komplett außerirdisch :-)

Comment: @schlingel es gibt ja immer noch gegenden, da fährt man einen Ort weiter, und die leute sprechen ein anderes Deutsch

Answer (score 7):

Another possibility for spoken language:

> [a*10^n] und ein paar Zerquetschte.

But usually, one would use this rather if `Zerquetschte` is of the order 10^{n-2} than 10^{n-1}.

Comment: Gefällt mir, aber wirklich, hat jemand so was gesagt? Wäre es nicht ein bisschen seltsam?

Comment: @c.p. inwiefern?? ich benutze diese Wendung auch sehr häufig..

Comment: Ich hab das mit dem 10^n-1/2 noch nicht ganz verstanden. .. wenn es das meint, was ich denke, dann halte ich das für nicht "korrekt"

Comment: @Vogel612 Toscho meint vielleicht, dass *Zerquetschte* bedeutet ein "dreihundert und ein paar Zerquetsche" für eine zweistellige Zahl, wobei er die nächsten zwei Ziffer verachtet hat.

Comment: @c.p. Diese Ausdrucksweise ist in Wien bekannt. Allerdings wird sie meist nur bei Geldbeträgen verwendet.

Comment: @miracle173 Diese Ausdrucksweise ist nicht nur in Wien bekannt. Ich war auch noch nie in Wien.

Comment: nun habe ich soeben diesen Ausdruck im Fernsehen auf Sat1 (Österreich)  gehört (der Betrag "4000 und ein paar Zerquetschte" wurde erwähnt) in der synchronisierten Fassung der Fernsehserie "House of Cards / Der Wasserturm". Da muss ich dem Ausdruck eine gewisse Überregionalität wohl zubilligen.

Comment: in Berlin sagt man das auch so...

Answer (score 4):

Another possibilities for written language:

> Zwanzig und ein bisschen (was)
>
> etwas mehr als Zwanzig / etwas weniger als Dreißig
>
> zwischen Zwanzig und Dreißig

Answer (score 4):

Adding some more possibilities (in brackets given the case when they are fewer):

> Es waren **gut** (knapp) 20 Zuschauer im Raum.
>   Gestern waren es **kaum mehr** (etwas weniger) als 20 Besucher.
>   **Über** (unter) 20 Gäste kamen zu spät.
>   Der Kaufpreis wird **mindestens** (höchstens) 20 Euro betragen.

These expressions, like the already given ones are mostly exchangeable.

Answer (score 3):

Ich würde `zwanzigirgendwas` (zwanzig-irgendwas) verwenden.

Unter `zwanzigirgendwastausend` (zwanzig-irgendwas-tausend) könnte man auch etwas > 21.000 verstehen (das *irgendwas*  bezieht sich auf die zwanzig). Der Ausdruck hört sich aber etwas holprig an.

`zwanzigtausendirgendwas` wäre etwas zwischen 20.000 - 21.000 (eher im unteren Bereich) - das *irgendwas* bezieht sich auf die zwanzigtausend.

Comment: `irgendundzwanzig` würde ich vorziehen (mündlich!) oder `irgendwievielhundertirgendundzwanzig`

Answer (score 1):

In southern Germany (eastern part -> Bavaria) we say for 'about twenty':

> Stück oder 20

Anyway, following expressions also are very common in the southern region:

> paar-und-zwanzig
>
> ...und ein paar Zerquetschte