# eine gute Stunde

Tags: meaning

> Teig in Folie wickeln und eine gute Stunde kühl stellen.

Wofür steht hier "gute", welche Bedeutung bringt das bei?
Ich habe bemerkt, dass das mit den Zeitbegriffen verwendet wird, aber was äußert das?

Comment: At least related [question](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/8687/1696).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Siehe [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/gut) : im Zusammenhang mit solchen Zeitangaben steht "gut" an der Stelle für "mindestens", "etwas mehr als angegeben". Im Beispiel:

> Teig in Folie wickeln und mindestens eine Stunde kühl stellen.

bzw.

> Teig in Folie wickeln und etwas länger als eine Stunde kühl stellen.

Die Bedeutung ist also: man sollte den Teig auf jeden Fall länger als 60 Minuten kühl stellen, eher 70 oder 80 Minuten.